# Improve HED algorithm for edge detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on an image processing task using python which depends mainly in detecting the grains in the image of soil samples so the first step in the processing process is edge detection ,I use HED algorithm (holistically nested edge detection ) for this step rather than using other edge detection functions in python as canny or sobel .
However , I face a problem in detecting the grains of fine soil particles as sand samples images shown below . I am asking if there is modification can be done on the image or the algorithm to improve edge detection to get the borders of the grains or as maximum as possible of the grains.
This is the used algorithm and results of using this algorithm in edge detection.

[image]
[image]
    # USAGE
    # python detect_edges_image.py --edge-detector hed_model --image images/guitar.jpg

```
# import the necessary packages
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import easygui
import pandas as pd
path = easygui.fileopenbox()
print(path)
hdir = os.path.dirname(path)
print(hdir)
hfilename = os.path.basename(path)
print(hfilename)
hname = os.path.splitext(hfilename)[0]
print(hname)
houtname = hname+"_out.jpg"
print(houtname)
hout = os.path.sep.join([hdir,houtname])
print(hout)

# # construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
# ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# ap.add_argument("-d", "--edge-detector", type=str, required=True,
#   help="path to OpenCV's deep learning edge detector")
# ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", type=str, required=True,
#   help="path to input image")
# args = vars(ap.parse_args())

class CropLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, params, blobs):
        # initialize our starting and ending (x, y)-coordinates of
        # the crop
        self.startX = 0
        self.startY = 0
        self.endX = 0
        self.endY = 0

    def getMemoryShapes(self, inputs):
        # the crop layer will receive two inputs -- we need to crop
        # the first input blob to match the shape of the second one,
        # keeping the batch size and number of channels
        (inputShape, targetShape) = (inputs[0], inputs[1])
        (batchSize, numChannels) = (inputShape[0], inputShape[1])
        (H, W) = (targetShape[2], targetShape[3])

        # compute the starting and ending crop coordinates
        self.startX = int((inputShape[3] - targetShape[3]) / 2)
        self.startY = int((inputShape[2] - targetShape[2]) / 2)
        self.endX = self.startX + W
        self.endY = self.startY + H

        # return the shape of the volume (we'll perform the actual
        # crop during the forward pass
        return [[batchSize, numChannels, H, W]]

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # use the derived (x, y)-coordinates to perform the crop
        return [inputs[0][:, :, self.startY:self.endY,
                self.startX:self.endX]]

# load our serialized edge detector from disk
print("[INFO] loading edge detector...")

fpath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
fdir =  os.path.dirname(fpath)
print(fdir)
protoPath = os.path.sep.join([fdir,"hed_model", "deploy.prototxt"])
print(protoPath)
modelPath =  os.path.sep.join([fdir,"hed_model","hed_pretrained_bsds.caffemodel"])
print(modelPath)

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoPath, modelPath)

# register our new layer with the model
cv2.dnn_registerLayer("Crop", CropLayer)

# load the input image and grab its dimensions
image = cv2.imread('D:\My work\MASTERS WORK\SAND - UNIFORM\sand_180pxfor1cm(130,120,75).jpg')
# image =cv2.equalizeHist(img)
# image = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image1,10,20)
(H, W) = image.shape[:2]
# print(image.shape[:2])
# image.shape[:2] =(H*3, W*3)ho
# image = cv2.resize(image,0.5)

# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and perform Canny
# edge detection
print("[INFO] performing Canny edge detection...")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
# blurred = cv2.addWeighted(gray,1.5,blurred,-0.5,0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred,30, 150)


# construct a blob out of the input image for the Holistically-Nested
# Edge Detector

# cc = cv2.cvtColor(canny, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
# image = image+cc

# mean = (104.00698793, 116.66876762, 122.67891434),

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scalefactor=1.0, size=(W, H),
                             # mean=(110,95,95),
                             # mean=(104.00698793, 116.66876762, 122.67891434),
                            # mean=(104, 116, 122),
                             mean=(130, 120, 75),
                            #  mean=(145, 147, 180),
                             swapRB= False, crop=False)
print( blob)
cv2.waitKey(0)
# set the blob as the input to the network and perform a forward pass
# to compute the edges
print("[INFO] performing holistically-nested edge detection...")
net.setInput(blob)
hed = net.forward()
hed = cv2.resize(hed[0, 0], (W, H))
hed = (255 * hed).astype("uint8")
# show the output edge detection results for Canny and
# Holistically-Nested Edge Detection
cv2.imshow("Input", image)
cv2.imshow("Canny", canny)
cv2.imshow("HED", hed)
cv2.imwrite(hout, hed)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Morphological operations such as [erosion](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) can be helpful in this.

Comment: @geekY How to overlay the detected edges back to original image